# Definition of integrable return time

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$ be an ergodic measure preserving dynamical system and $Y\subset X$ with $\mu(Y)>0$.

The first return to $Y$ is the function $R:Y\to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $R(y)=\inf\{n\in \mathbb{N} \mid T^n(y)\in Y\}$. This can easily be extended to a $kth$ return time, where $k$ is any natural number.

In reading papers, I keep coming across the notion of "integrable return times". I can not seem to find any definition online (all ergodic theory notes refer to first returns), but if I was to hazard a guess, the following definition seems natural:

"An integrable return time is an integrable function $S:Y\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $T^{S(y)}\in Y$".

My question is: Is the above definition correct? If not, is anyone aware of the correct definition?

Answer (score 1):

> It means that $R$ is integrable on $Y$.

Then all $k$th return times are integrable. Actually, you can forget about "ergodic" in your first sentence. Nothing changes.

But you should not use your definition, not all such functions are integrable if $R$ is integrable (notice the $\inf$ in the definition) even if they are measurable.

Comment: Thanks. The following paper considers an integrable return time and mentions it is not necessarily the first return time. A link is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.01853.pdf, page 3. By this, do you think the authors are referring to a $kth$ return time which is integrable?

Comment: Moreover, when the measure is invariant, isn't the first return time ALWAYS integrable by Kac's Lemma?

Comment: Maps with singularities need not have an integrable first return time and thus the need for the integrability condition. Sometimes, in Pesin theory (of which this paper is particular case) it is convenient to consider higher iterates. As I wrote: higher return times become integrable, but the opposite is not the case and it may be better to require something for a higher return time (although of course unnecessary).

Comment: check (H1) on http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/dt328/papers/Revised_GENRET-Feb,16.pdf. In in, the authors define a general return time $(\phi)$ in terms of consecutive returns to $Y$ ($\tau_p$).

Comment: They are proceeding by induction, so what is the relation to what I wrote?

Comment: Okay, scrap that previous message. However, I found a paper which uses the definition I gave in my original question: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.07775, page 5.

Comment: Sure, the same as above. Again they are using induction. They repeat again and again the setting of Young, rather formal indeed.